# Running nodejs Script to create table from local machine terminates Cloud SQL connection

Tags: node.js, postgresql, google-cloud-sql, knex.js, cloud-sql-proxy

I am trying to run the command `node createTable.js $DB_USER $DB_PW $DB_NAME $CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME` from windows power shell as it is indicated in the Google cloud Platform nodejs samples for connecting to [cloudsql from cloudrun using knex in this repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/cloud-sql/postgres/knex).

I have intalled and Started the Cloud SQL Proxy and followed all the instructions including adding service accounts in the sample. But each time I run the createTable.js script from power Shell, I get the following errors in Powershell:

[image]

When I inspect the logs, I get the following in Cloud SQL

> "db=cloudsqladmin,user=cloudsqladmin FATAL: terminating connection due
> to administrator command"

See attached image below:
[image]

I don't know what possibly could be causing the error.

PS: I have tried to connect to cloud SQL from Cloud console and this worked fine, However, When I try this from my local machine using Powershell, It shows the above error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: "terminating connection due to administrator command" sounds like the account or connection is configured to not be allowed to run such commands, e.g. only run queries but not create tables. Have you checked that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to connect to Cloud SQL using the instance's public IP address. If you're connecting through the Cloud SQL Proxy, you should be connecting to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` at whatever port the proxy is running on.
To launch the proxy in TCP mode, run:

```
Start-Process -filepath "C:\<path to proxy exe>" -ArgumentList "-instances=<project-id>:<region>:<instance-name>=tcp:5432 -credential_file=<CREDENTIALS_JSON_FILE>"
```

Then run

```
$env:DB_USER $env:DB_PW $env:DB_NAME $env:CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME node createTable.js --dbHost "127.0.0.1:5432"
```

The proxy allows you to connect to your instance without having to add your machine's IP to the instance's allowlist. If you try to connect directly and your IP isn't on the allowlist, you'll get an error.

Comment: Wow! Thank you Shubha, you saved my day! I was doing it the wrong way as you predicted. I was trying to connect with the instance's public IP address, I then changed to 127.0.0.1:5432 and eureka! It worked. I have a question though: I was using my Cloud SQL instance's DB_NAME and DB_PASS, when I Tried it the console prompted "Failed to create 'votes' table: error: password authentication failed for user "postgres". I had to change my password to my local postgres password before it worked. Why is that? I actually want to connect to My Cloud SQL instance. How do I do that?

Comment: What port is the Cloud SQL proxy accepting connections on? Are you getting output that starts with "New connection" from the proxy when you connect? You might be connecting to a local instance instead of Cloud SQL if you're not getting any output from the proxy.Try turning off your local postgres server, or changing the port for the Cloud SQL Proxy, and connecting to the new port when you run the script.

Comment: After I turned off the local postgres instance, I get the following error "Failed to create 'votes' table: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432"

Comment: What command are you using to  run the proxy and what output do you get? I would double-check that the proxy is accepting connections at 127.0.0.1:5432, and that you're using the correct database name and password for your Cloud SQL instance.